# Logging response time of Zulu Proxy Request

Tags: java, proxy, netflix-zuul

We would like to capture the response time of every request that is handled by a Zuul Proxy Server to be used for performance monitoring. A Zuul Filter seems like the logical way of doing it but given the structure of the Zuul Filter there doesn't seem an easy way of capturing elapsed time.
Can anyone shed some light on how we could achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I also struggled with Zuul filters to get basic metrics.

[Spring Actuator trace](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-tracing.html) gives a lot of info out the box. Simply use "/trace" to view the :

- **timestamp**
- **timeTaken**
- **HTTP status code**

It's prefect for Zuul

```
[
    {
        "timestamp": 1499429507097,
        "info": {
            "method": "GET",
            "path": "/index.html",
            "headers": {
                "request": {
                    "host": "localhost:8765",
                    "connection": "keep-alive",
                    "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
                    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/58.0.3029.110 Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36",
                    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
                    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch, br",
                    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
                    "cookie": "zbx_sessionid=02ac46186474dbd668d7abe0f78705c9"
                },
                "response": {
                    "X-Application-Context": "application:8765",
                    "Last-Modified": "Fri, 07 Jul 2017 10:52:42 GMT",
                    "Cache-Control": "no-store",
                    "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
                    "Content-Type": "text/html",
                    "Content-Length": "446",
                    "Date": "Fri, 07 Jul 2017 12:11:47 GMT",
                    "status": "200"
                }
            },
            "timeTaken": "3"
        }
    },
```

**However**, the standard [InMemoryTraceRepository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/trace/InMemoryTraceRepository.java) gave me stats on "/health" and even "/trace", but I am only interested in ***POSTS*** that go to Zuul. So I just extended [InMemoryTraceRepository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/trace/InMemoryTraceRepository.java) and provided it as a @Bean.

```
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.InMemoryTraceRepository;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.Trace;

public class ZuulInMemoryTraceRepository extends InMemoryTraceRepository {

  public ZuulInMemoryTraceRepository(int maxSize) {
    setCapacity(maxSize);
  }

  public Collection<DateTimeTaken> getStats(){
    return fifo;
  }

  public void setReverse(boolean reverse) {
    super.setReverse(reverse);
  }

  @Override
  public void setCapacity(int capacity) {
    super.setCapacity(capacity);
  }

  @Override
  public List<Trace> findAll() {
    return super.findAll();
  }

  @Override
  public void add(Map<String, Object> map) {

    Object method = map.get("method");
    if (!"POST".equals(method)) {
      return;
    }
    Object timeTaken = map.get("timeTaken");//timeTaken is a String
    //log timeTaken
    super.add(map);
  }
}
```

***In my @Configuration I added:***

```
@Bean
public ZuulInMemoryTraceRepository myZuulInMemoryTraceRepository() {
  return new ZuulInMemoryTraceRepository(10000);
}
```

Alternatively you can add a custom object to a [EvictingQueue](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/EvictingQueue.java) of a fixed size in ZuulInMemoryTraceRepository. Finally expose a restful webservice to expose a the EvictingQueue like my getStats(). This json can then be used to draw a pretty response time graph.

```
@Override
public void add(Map<String, Object> map) {
  super.add(map);
  Object method = map.get("method");
  if (!"POST".equals(method)) {
    return;
  }
  Object timeTaken = map.get("timeTaken");//timeTaken is a String
  if (timeTaken != null) {
    synchronized (fifo) {
      //Make your own DateTimeTaken
      fifo.add(new DateTimeTaken(new Date(), timeTaken.toString()));
    }
  }
}
```

In my stats @RestController:

```
@Autowired
ZuulInMemoryTraceRepository zuulInMemoryTraceRepository;

@RequestMapping("/stats")
public Collection<DateTimeTaken> getAll() {
  return zuulInMemoryTraceRepository.getStats();
}
```